# RegEx pattern to match a string between two characters, but exclude the characters

Tags: php, regex

Greetings all,

I have yet another RegEx question.  I have done hours of searching but apparently I have missed the one key article I need.

I need to use preg_match() in PHP to match a string that is between parenthesis, but NOT have the parenthesis show up in the result.  I have seen examples of similar issues, but I believe my problem is different because it's actually parenthesis that I am dealing with, with is a meta character in RegEx.  Any merit to that?

Anyways...

String is:

```
     "200 result=1 (SIP/100-00000033)"
```

Current code is:

```
preg_match("/\((.*)\)/s", $res, $matches);
```

$matches[0] becomes:

```
     "(SIP/100-00000033)"
```

What I WANT is:

```
     "SIP/100-00000033"
```

I apologize because I'm sure this is VERY simple but I'm just not grasping it.  Would anyone care to educate me?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You're telling me you didn't check the contents of `$matches`!?

Comment: @Nick:  I do understand why you threw a "stupid" rock at me.  I didn't specify that I was using this script through Asterisk, which does not permit the use of "var_dump" - Admittedly I could have used other mechanisms to check the contents of the array, but I simply didn't think of it.  But we all have to learn through experience.  So thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it all refers to the way you group items in the regular expression. Your solution is actually correct, you're just using the wrong index for matches. Try:

```
$matches[1]
```

If that somehow gives errors, post'em and we'll fix.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want the full match to exclude the parentheses, you can use look-ahead and look-behind [assertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
preg_match('/(?<=\().*(?=\))/s', $res, $matches);
```